# Import STL model in delphi firemonkey TModel3D

Tags: stl, firemonkey

As I can see in documentation Delphi Firemonkey TModel3D can only import 3D file in .ase, .dae, .obj formats.

Does anyone know how to import STL files in TModel3D ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?  It's really helpful to others if you can post something that you have tried, even if it doesn't work.  It shows initiative on your part and let's other gauge your experience level.

Comment: I'm, currently, abording this task. I'm doing it loading the data of an STL in the TMesh.Data property of a TMesh component inserted into a TViewport Component. 
I'm having a lot of problems, of course.  
If you are interested in the solution I can share with you the code and we can collaborate.